# Randomly sampling one or more levels of a grouping variable in R

Tags: r, variables, random, grouping

Hello I have a data table where I have data across grouping variables like this. The groups are Site, Species and Season, and the response is Conductance. I want to randomly pick a level of species for a site and find the average conductance for the random pick of the level of species. I would like to randomly pick one, two or more levels of species from the grouping variable Species. How should I go about it? thanks in advance

```
Site      Species    Season      Conductance
1          Species1   Dry           20
1          Species2   Dry           30
1          Species3   Dry           40
1          Species1   Dry           25
1          Species2   Dry           30
1          Species3   Dry           35
2          Species1   Dry           30
2          Species2   Dry           24
2          Species2   Dry           25
2          Species4   Dry           30
2          Species4   Dry           32
2          Species4   Dry           30
1          Species1   wet           26
1          Species2   wet           24
1          Species3   wet           30
2          Species1   wet           32
2          Species4   wet           30
2          Species4   wet           28
```

Comment: if the language is r, you should use the r tag to notify people watching that tag, so they can find your question

Comment: What have you tried? Which language or database are you using? The question is vague. Also, tag the question with the relevant technologies, if you want the right people to read it.

Comment: I am using R and yes, should have tagged it appropriately

Answer (score 0):

This question needs to be clarified, but here's a starting point for sampling in R:

```
data(iris)

# Sample 5 random rows
iris[sample(nrow(iris), 5), ]

# Sample 1 random Species
sample(unique(iris$Species),1) # Where all groups equally likely
iris[sample(nrow(iris), 1), c("Species")]  # Where probability is proportionate to group prevalence
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anna for the code,  Ya my question should have been clearer. I am using R, and with the code you suggested I was able to randomly pick species. However what I want to do is to randomly pick species and find mean conductance of the randomly picked species for each of the two sites. In fact I would like to learn  to create a loop to randomly pick species and populate a table that stores mean conductance for those species at each of the two sites. Thanks a lot again to you and the forum.